# How to determine the number of parameters/keywords of a selector

Tags: objective-c

I know it can be done by decoding the selector name returned from sel_getName.

But is there any other more convenient preloaded info in runtime that I can get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the docs for `NSMethodSignature`, and the `-methodSignatureForSelector:` method of `NSObject`.

You can ask an object for the method signature of any selector it implements, and you can then send a `-numberOfArguments` message to the method signature instance.

Comment: what if neither target or target class is known?

Answer (score 4):

** 1st Solution **

The solution is to mix Objective-C runtime function and the [NSMethodSignature](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/index.html) class.

First you need to include some headers

```
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <objc/objc-class.h>
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
```

Then, wherever you want, starting with your selector, you get the parameter's count (note that every method has two implicit parameters **self** and **_cmd**, so you have to not count them to have only the parameters):

```
SEL sel = @selector(performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:);
Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], sel);
const char *encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(m);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:encoding];
int allCount = [signature numberOfArguments]; // The parameter count including the self and the _cmd ones
int parameterCount = allCount - 2; // Count only the method's parameters
```

** 2nd Solution **

Convert your selector to a NSString and count the ":" characters. Not sure it is reliable.

Comment: why not just `NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSObject instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:sel];`

Comment: Counting the colons will work, at least on every version of Obj-C I've seen since 1989.  ;-)